# nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1 message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme

I am trying to find a best model fitting on my data using `library(nlme)` and `lme` function in R. Here is my model when the slope is fixed:

```
FixedRopeLength <- lme(EnergyCost~ RopeLength, 
  data = data, 
  random=~1|Subject, method = "ML")
summary(FixedRopeLength)
```

---

To see whether a random slope provides a better model than a fixed slope, I let the slope to vary across Subject as follows:

```
RandomRopeLength <- lme(EnergyCost~RopeLength,
 data = data, 
 random=~RopeLength|Subject, method = "ML")
summary(RandomRopeLength)
```

---

However, I got this error:

> Error in lme.formula(EnergyCost ~ RopeLength, data = data, random =
> ~RopeLength |  :    nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
> message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)

Any solution??

Answer (score 4):

`?lme` shows that there is a `control` argument, which redirects you to `?lmerControl`, which gives you

> msMaxIter: maximum number of iterations for the optimization step
> inside the ‘lme’ optimization.  Default is ‘50’.

and

> msMaxEval: maximum number of evaluations of the objective function
> permitted for nlminb.  Default is ‘200’.

These correspond to `eval.max` and `iter.max` from `?nlminb`.  Since I'm not sure which of these is the problem, I would re-run the model with

```r
control = lmeControl(msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000)
```

However, I'll warn you that once you have a problem that experiences numerical problems with the default parameter settings, adjusting the parameter settings may just lead to other problems farther down the line ...

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much for your help. Your code worked. I only needed to justify your code based on lme function. Here is the code which can be used for aforementioned error:

```r
RandomRopeLength <- lme(EnergyCost~RopeLength, 
   data = data, 
   random=~RopeLength|Subject, method = "ML", 
    control =list(msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000))
summary(RandomRopeLength)
```